# Sencha touch nested list with number field and button for list items?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, nested-lists

I have this following code and i want to display images and other html elements as items of the nested list.

Can this be achieved?

> My code is

```
Ext.setup({
    tabletStartupScreen: 'tablet_startup.png',
    phoneStartupScreen: 'phone_startup.png',
    icon: 'icons/logo4_1.png',
    glossOnIcon: false,

    title: 'Item List',
    fullscree: true,
    onReady: function() {

        var data = {
            title: 'Item List',
            text: 'Groceries',
            items: [{
                text: 'Beverages',
                imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                items: [{
                    text: 'Water',
                    imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                    items: [{
                        text: 'Sparkling',
                        imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                        leaf: true
                    }, {
                        text: 'Still',
                        imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                        leaf: true
                    }]
                }, {
                    text: 'Coffee',
                    imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Espresso',
                    imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Redbull',
                    imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Coke',
                    imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Diet Coke',
                    imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                text: 'Fruits',
                imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                items: [{
                    text: 'Bananas',
                    imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Watermelon',
                    imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Grapes',
                    imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                    items: [{
                        text: 'Black Grapes',
                        leaf: true
                    }, {
                        text: 'Green Grapes',
                        leaf: true
                    }]
                }, {
                    text: 'Pear',
                    imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Apple',
                    imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                text: 'Bread and Bakery',
                imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                items: [{
                    text: 'Bread',
                    imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                    items: [{
                        text: 'White Bread',
                        imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                        leaf: true,
                    }, {
                        text: 'Brown Bread',
                        imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                        leaf: true,
                    }, {
                        text: 'Sandwich Bread',
                        imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                        leaf: true,
                    }]
                }, {
                    text: 'Pretzels',
                    imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Cup Cakes',
                    imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                text: 'Personal Care',
                imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                items: [{
                    text: 'Shampoo',
                    imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                    items: [{
                        text: 'Dove',
                        imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                        leaf: true,
                    }, {
                        text: 'Sunsilk',
                        imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                        leaf: true,
                    }, {
                        text: 'Garnier',
                        imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                        leaf: true,
                    }]
                }, {
                    text: 'Soaps',
                    imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                    items: [{
                        text: 'Dove',
                        imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                        leaf: true,
                    }, {
                        text: 'Pears',
                        imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                        leaf: true,
                    }, {
                        text: 'Lux',
                        imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                        leaf: true,
                    }]
                }, {
                    text: 'Hair Oil',
                    imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                    items: [{
                        text: 'Vatika',
                        imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                        leaf: true,
                    }, {
                        text: 'Almond Oil',
                        imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                        leaf: true,
                    }, {
                        text: 'Parachute Coconut oil',
                        imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                        leaf: true,
                    }]
                }, {
                    text: 'Body Lotions',
                    imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                    items: [{
                        text: 'Dove',
                        imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                        leaf: true,
                    }, {
                        text: 'Ponds',
                        imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                        leaf: true,
                    }, {
                        text: 'Nivea',
                        imgURL: '\images\beverage\colas.jpg',
                        leaf: true,
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        };

        Ext.regModel('ListItem', {
            fields: ['text', 'imgURL'],
            //fields: [{name: 'text', type: 'string'},{name: 'imageURL', type: 'string'}],

        });

        var store = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
            model: 'ListItem',
            root: data,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                reader: {
                    type: 'tree',
                    root: 'items'
                }
            }
        });

        var leftNav = new Ext.NestedList({
            fullscreen: true,
            dock: 'left',
            useTitleAsBackText: true,
            title: 'Item List',
            icon: 'icons/logo4_1.png',
            itemTpl: '<img src="{imgURL}" width="100" heigh="100"></img><span>{text}</span> <span><button>Add to Cart</button>',
            width: '350',
            image: 'image',
            dockedItems: [{
                html: '<img src="icons/logo4_1.png" width="100" height="40"/>',
                dock: 'top',
            }],
            store: store,
        });

        new Ext.Panel({
            fullscreen: true,

            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            defaults: {
                flex: 1
            },
            dockedItems: [leftNav]
        });
        if (Ext.is.Phone) {
            fullscreen: true;
        }
    }
});
```

Though am using the `imgURl` field its not working.

Plz help.. Answers appreciated..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the template of your nested list items. You can do it by adding a `getItemTextTpl` attribute to you nested list config

```
getItemTextTpl: function(node){
    return '{imgURL} - {text}';
}
```

You can take a look at how I used `getItemTextTpl` [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468787/dynamic-item-template-in-nestedlist)

Comment: Its returning the image url in a string format.. am not getting the image.. I have started learning sencha touch from past two days can you plz help me out..

Comment: and also what do i have to do if i want the html elements only for few items and not all??? any idea

Comment: The best way is to add a bool object in your model like 'isDisplayed' that you'd have to set to false or true whether you want to display it or not. And then you need to return an XTemplate using the isDiplayed key in your getItemTextTpl

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does not work for me -- what worked was setting the itemTpl inside the listConfig config item in the NestedList:

```
Ext.define('project.view.FooList', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.NestedList',
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        title: 'Foo, bro',
        listConfig: {
            itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('{text}, bro')
        },
        store: 'FooStore'
    }
});
```

Comment: Special thanks to you! The accepted answer lead in ExtJS 6.0.1 to a `Cannot override method getItemTextTpl on Ext.dataview.NestedList instance.` Exception. Your solution worked! Really helped me! For more information: [link](https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?305313-Modern-NestedList-getItemTextTpl-getTitleTextTpl-causes-error)